# How do I compare between two images in python?

Tags: python

My code is:

```
import cv2

from PIL import Image

import numpy as np

img=cv2.imread("IMG040.jpg")

img2=cv2.imread("IMG040.jpg")

p1 = np.array(img)

p2 = np.array(img2)

img3=img-img2

p3 = np.array(img3)

if p3==0 :
    print "the same"
else: 
    print"not the same"


but I have this problem
File "part2.py", line 10, in <module>
    if p3==0 :
```

Error message:

```
**ValueError:** The truth value of an array with more than one element is
ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Did you read the error message?

Comment: yes but I don't understand it can you help me

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html

Comment: You need to compare all elements one by one. If the first is different you can leave and tell the whole is different.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
p3==0
```

Creates a boolean numpy array. The Python `if` statement does not know how to interpret this whole array as being true or false. That's what the error message means. You presumably want to know if all of the elements are zero and that is why the error message suggests you should use `all()`.

To do this, you would end up changing the line to

```
if (p3==0).all():
```

However it is better to compare numpy arrays with the `allclose` method, which can account for numerical errors. So try replacing this

```
img3=img-img2

p3 = np.array(img3)

if p3==0 :
    print "the same"
else: 
    print"not the same"
```

with

```
if np.allclose(img, img2):
    print "the same"
else:
    print "not the same"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the if statement like this:

```
if np.all(p3==0):
    print 'The same'
else:
    print 'Not the same'
```